# How is a merge conflict valid in a React, Typescript project

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I found the code, pasted, below checked in to our React/Typescript - JSX/TSX project. It contains a Git merge conflict that hasn't been resolved.

The code builds (through Fuse-box) and runs in the browser!

The "transpiled" code results in the top element being resolved as the root element of our component and the second element (beginning ".app-container") being ignored.

It appears, that in some situations, git merge conflicts can be ignored through TSX/JSX interpretation / parsing / transpilation.

My questions are: How does this work? Is this behaviour intentional?

```
export const App: SFC = () => (
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <Provider store={window.uglySolution}>
        <Router history={customHistory}>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Welcome}/>
                <Route exact path='/advice' component={PageLayout}/>
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
                <Route exact path='/manage' component={ManageLayout}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
=======
    <div className='app-container'>
        <Provider store={window.uglySolution}>
            <Router history={customHistory}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Welcome}/>
                    <Route exact path='/advice' component={PageLayout}/>
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
                    <Route exact path='/manage' component={ManageLayout}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    </div>
>>>>>>> f81b0b1b458e3d41f91faa2e726be6d88a35d9f8
);
```

Comment: if not told otherwise tsc is going to do it's best to ignore any bad code you might have. It might happen that this would generate valid code even if the input is wrong.It's the default behaviour, but I would not count on it.. solve your conflicts. :)

Comment: also, in this case.. I would assume the merge text from git just ends up in the template.. since from the point of view of tsc is going to be text

Comment: @toskv - how would I tell Typescript to ignore "bad code" (your "otherwise" statement in this case)?

Comment: it's the `--noEmitOnError` compiler option that controls what happens, the default is false. You can see all configs here. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: In your case, it might be that what you have there is valid jsx, because the git markings are considered to be html text and ignored by the compiler. You can blame git for not having better merge mechanics.. :D

Comment: @toskv indeed, or you can blame SGML for having an awful syntax that has become popular for  no good reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite a late answer (almost a year later) but in case somebody is googling this and wondering about the same thing. Yes, the behavior intentional there is code right at the typescript lexer to handle git merge conflicts! Note: skip trivia defaults to true on the parser.

```
if (isConflictMarkerTrivia(text, pos)) {
  pos = scanConflictMarkerTrivia(text, pos, error);
  if (skipTrivia) {
    continue;
}
else {
    return token = SyntaxKind.ConflictMarkerTrivia;
  }
}
```

And below is the code that handles merge conflicts:

```
function scanConflictMarkerTrivia(text: string, pos: number, error?: (diag: DiagnosticMessage, pos?: number, len?: number) => void) {
    if (error) {
        error(Diagnostics.Merge_conflict_marker_encountered, pos, mergeConflictMarkerLength);
    }

    const ch = text.charCodeAt(pos);
    const len = text.length;

    if (ch === CharacterCodes.lessThan || ch === CharacterCodes.greaterThan) {
        while (pos < len && !isLineBreak(text.charCodeAt(pos))) {
            pos++;
        }
    }
    else {
        Debug.assert(ch === CharacterCodes.bar || ch === CharacterCodes.equals);
        // Consume everything from the start of a ||||||| or ======= marker to the start
        // of the next ======= or >>>>>>> marker.
        while (pos < len) {
            const currentChar = text.charCodeAt(pos);
            if ((currentChar === CharacterCodes.equals || currentChar === CharacterCodes.greaterThan) && currentChar !== ch && isConflictMarkerTrivia(text, pos)) {
                break;
            }

            pos++;
        }
    }

    return pos;
}
```

sources: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0ef0b7adea643a4a28cf9ada1476ff5650a1a9f2/src/compiler/scanner.ts#L1604
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0ef0b7adea643a4a28cf9ada1476ff5650a1a9f2/src/compiler/scanner.ts#L565

Answer (score 0):

> It appears, that in some situations git merge conflicts can be resolved though Tax/JSX interpretation / parsing / transpilation.

The given code *is a compile error*. That said *compile errors don't mean you don't get any JS generated*. There is an option `noEmitOnError` that will prevent this, but that said you should see a compile error and fix it even without this option.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html